# How to solve " String cannot be resolved to a variable" when string scan is in if statement?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Minimum reproducible example:

```
int value=scan.nextInt();

String S1=scan.nextInt();

if(value==2)
String S2=scan.nextLine();

//some lines of code

if(value==2)
driver.findElement(By.id("id2")).sendKeys(S2);
```

I am getting "S2 cannot be resolved to a variable" due to the line:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("id2")).sendKeys(S2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code

```
if(value==2)
    String S2=scan.nextLine();
```

the variable `S2` goes immediately out of scope.

try

```
String S2 = "";
if(value==2)
    S2=scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: I upvoted but I am still new so it does not count, tried to accept the answer and it told me to wait for 4 minutes, now I did.